# JSP, JSTL forEach with ArrayList and select box option

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, foreach, liferay

I have a portlet jsp with a form. The content of the form is sent and stored to the server. The next time the site with the portlet is rendered, the form is prefilled with the values previously selected.
This works with one exception: one of my select boxes:

JSP:

```
// get value chosen before:
<% String projectAssistant = ... %> // This get's the correct string value

<aui:select name="<%=// assistant name %>">
    <c:forEach items="${iStaffList}" var="option">
        <aui:option value="${option}" selected="${option==projectAssistant ? true : false }">${option}</aui:option>
    </c:forEach>
</aui:select>
```

Controller:

```
ArrayList<String> staffList = _staffListAdapter.getStaffListAsStrings();
    renderRequest.setAttribute("iStaffList", staffList);
```

This results in a prefilled select box with all the options from my `ArrayList`. But when i select an option other from the first in the list, submit and then reload the page, again the first value is preselected and not the previously chosen one.

I have another select box prefilled from an basic `String[]` and this works fine. Here the code for the working select box:
JSP:

```
// get project status
<% String projectStatus = .... %>
<aui:select name="<%= //projectStatus name %>">
    <c:forEach items="${STATUS_OPTIONS}" var="option">
        <aui:option value="${option}" selected="${option==projectStatus ? true : false }">${option}</aui:option>
    </c:forEach>
</aui:select>
```

Controller:

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("STATUS_OPTIONS", ProjectStatusConstants.STATUUS);
```

Where

```
public class ProjectStatusConstants
{
  public static String[] STATUUS = {"", "Draft", "Submitted", "Passed",
                                    "Running", "Closed", "Rejected"};
}
```

What am i doing wrong here with the ArrayList, etc?

Kind Regards

**EDIT:** Forgot to say that the correct selected value gets sent back to the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was, that `projectAssistant` was not existing in my `pageContext` - so `${projectAssistant}` didn't work. I thought i could access the scriptlet variable via EL, too.

To correct this all i had to do was `<c:set var="projectAssistant" value="<%=projectAssistant %>" />` to make `<% String projectAssistant = ... %>`known as `projectAssistant` in my page context.